# How to write queries for DATE TIME data type in SQLITE iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

- In my sqlite data base I have a field for **time**.
- till now i used time with type '**varChar**'. it is working perfectly
- But now i need to change the type in to **DateTime.**
- how can i change the followin queries to convert from varchar to date & time type.
  -in my tabele columns are 'time'(DATETIME), 'Comments'(VARCHAR)

  - in select all method.

    ---

  (NSMutableArray *)selectAllFromDB
  {

  **time=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 0)];**

}
    ***_*_**

```
-in insert method

-(BOOL)insertIntoDB:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict
{
        time=[dict objectForKey:@"time"];

        if(sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [time UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            return NO;
        }

}
```

how to modify these queries for **date** data type

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

-(BOOL)insertIntoDB:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict

```
{

time=[dict objectForKey:@"time"];
```

if((sqlite3_bind_double(insert_statement, 1, [time timeIntervalSince1970])) != SQLITE_OK)

```
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: here "time" is not a string it NSDate type..
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString: time]; is shows a warning."incomplete ponter type sent to NSString"

my table having columns "1.time:DATETIME" "2.comments:VARCHAR"

here time is of type DATETIME in my table

Comment: when i use NSString for time in query it stores null value

Comment: ate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 1)];..

Sir i need to select time not the time interval sinc1971